# Excel - Subtracting a value from another value, pending a response in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula question in Excel...  How would I go about making a formula which would, based on a status column marked with "Done", automatically copy a value from a previous column, and paste it into another column?  I don't know if that is clear or not...

I have a scene of animated content...  In the scene are 400 frames to be animated (listed in the "frames column").  I want to add a status of the scene column, that once the use writes "Done", the frames column would be copied into a hidden "frames animated" column, therefore, updating a master "remaining" column later on, counting down the overall picture of how many frames are left to be animated in the film.

Please tell me this makes sense, and that further, one of you may be able to help me out with one such formula.  I am certain it is easy...  Just out of my artist mind's realm.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to give an example for us to better understand your question. Let me know if my answer is not enough or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `IF`

`=IF(A1="Done", B1)`

```
Done    | 1 | 1 <<< =IF(A1="Done", B1)
Done    | 2 | 2
Not yet | 3 |   <<< Empty
```

Modify the example to suit your columns.

Whatever value you put in the `B` column will be copied at `C`.